# Is there a resource for comparing categories of life along quantifiable dimensions such as species diversity, geographic range, total mass, etc?

Tags: taxonomy, biodiversity, measurement

Ideally what I would like is some sort of interactive, sliceable tabular data along the lines of my examples below. The curious individual specifies the level of taxonomic rank, e.g. Kingdom or Class etc., and then can choose to populate several rows from within that category with data on that category's "successfulness" as measured in various ways (of course all the data fields would be estimates)

```
CLASS        # OF SPECIES  TOT MASS   TOT RANGE    # INDIV.  # CELLS PER INDIV.
Insecta      ???           ???        ???          ???       ???
Mammalia     ???           ???        ???          ???       ???
<click to add a row>
```

But the user could select a different granularity, so e.g.

```
FAMILY       # OF SPECIES  TOT MASS   TOT RANGE    # INDIV.  # CELLS PER INDIV.
Formicidae   ???           ???        ???          ???       ???
Felidae      ???           ???        ???          ???       ???
```

The goal would be to be able to put "superlative" claims about various categories of life into context. I often read claims of a ____'s (species', genus', etc.) success based on one of these or other estimates, but have no intuitive way of attributing an absolute context to the number reported.

Furthermore, such a table / database would just help me form a clearer picture in my own head of "all the life out there" (that we know about). For example, if I wanted to learn all there is to know about every species of "cat" (I am on the internet, after all), how many species are we talking about? Probably on the order of dozens, versus thousands or tens of thousands for ants.

So far I've found "top 10"-style [lists](https://www.britannica.com/list/the-most-numerous-organisms-in-the-world) [and](http://tolweb.org/tree/) [the](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20150211-whats-the-most-dominant-life-form) [like](http://book.bionumbers.org/how-many-cells-are-there-in-an-organism/), but no single unified searchable tabular database.

Comment: Just putting this out there: as far as I know, there isn't an available comprehensive database like this... but maybe you (or others on this site?) could kick off putting one together!

Comment: If you put "No" as an answer, I'll happily upvote it until someone else says "yes" :P

Comment: you've got a deal!